# Why do these two rm commands produce different outputs?

Tags: bash, unix

In the first command, the root directory, i.e. `te`, is not deleted. In the second command, I am trying to add an exception not to delete files of type `.log` which ends up destroying the source directory. Why do these commands differ and what is the correct way to add an exception without deleting the original directory?

```
user:~/mnt/test$ rm -rf te/*
user:~/mnt/test$ ls
no.tar  te
user:~/mnt/test$ rm -rf te/* !(*.log)
user:~/mnt/test$ ls
no.tar
```

Comment: Yes, everything underneath te/ should be deleted (directories, files, and hidden files) but not te/ itself and not any file that has that .log extension. For simplicity sake, let's assume there will only be .log files directly under te/ and not in any subdirectories of it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [extglob pattern](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Pattern-Matching.html#Pattern-Matching) `!(*.log)` matches the directory `te` too as its name doesn't end with `.log`. To delete every file residing in `te` except those with the extension `log`, you should do:

```
shopt -s dotglob    # match hidden files too
echo rm -rf te/!(*.log)
```

Drop `echo` if you're happy with the output.